# R has magic number 'ëPNG' error

Tags: r

I have a R script that reads files and generates graphs automatically. It works when it runs the first time. If the .png files are there and the script needs to re-create them with the new data, I get this error:

```
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file 'test1.png' has magic number 'ëPNG'
   Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
Execution halted
```

what does this error mean? I tried to use source("filename"), it did not work either.

thanks,

Comment: you're trying to load a `png` file and not an `RData` file ... (or you've overwritten your R data files with PNGs ...)

Comment: I am trying to generate png files like this: png(paste(x$var1,x$var,".png",sep=""), height=850, width=750) I see in the name of the file that there is a space before the .png. Do you think this is causing it?

Comment: no. The error message is fairly specific and diagnostic in this case -- you are asking R to `load()` a file called `test1.png`, and, unsurprisingly, it's not in RData format. This kind of piecemeal remote debugging is going to get very frustrating for everyone ... try reading http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 and see if you can reduce your problem to something short and replicable that you can post here (in the process you're likely to discover your problem for yourself)

Comment: you are right. I used setwd to change the directory of the saved images, it worked. hurrayy.

Answer (score 2):

I had to split the directories that I was working with. I am outputting to another folder as below resolves the problem.

setwd("C/img")

Comment: Also, why is this post down voted. I have never seen that error and couldn't find much resources to help with that error. I am learning R and I am amazed by it everyday. I participate in this site a lot and down voting my post does not help anything.

Comment: I dont understand why this post was down voted. What does that error message mean? It is not descriptive. I know some of you are familiar with R and have been around. Bur for a new bie, that error message does not mean anything. Now it does mean something to me and if I see it again, I will definetely know. Also, if anybody new to R and saw that error, this post will help them greatly. Please if you cant contribute in a positive way, stop contributing at all. The purpose of this site is to collaborate not destroy -- at least I hope.

Comment: @Andrei, your closing and down voting my post did not help anything. My account is blocked and cannot post anything on this site. Congradulations!!