# "bad restore file magic number" error in R

Tags: r, loading

As in [What could cause a "bad magic number" error when loading an R workspace and how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463583/what-could-cause-a-bad-magic-number-error-when-loading-an-r-workspace-and-how?rq=1) and [R has magic number 'ëPNG' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806867/r-has-magic-number-epng-error?rq=1), I'm getting a *bad restore file magic number* error:

```
> load("fossilien.dat")
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘fossilien.dat’ has magic number '"Samp'
   Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

Using the `source` function gives me a different error (similar to [unexpected string constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377206/unexpected-string-constant)):

```
> source("fossilien.dat")
Error in source("fossilien.dat") : 
  fossilien.dat:1:10: unexpected string constant
1: "Sample" "Sname"
            ^
```

This is especially frustrating as I'm confident the source of data is legit - its for a homework problem: ftp://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/WBL/fossilien.dat

None of the SO questions above were really answered properly so I thought I would try again.

Some details about my R installation:

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0"
$version.string
[1] "R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `read.table` function ended up working: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html

```
> fossildata <- read.table("fossilien.dat")
```

EDIT by CGW:   `load` is for files in `.rdata` format, while your `fossilien.dat` clearly is an ASCII table. `source` *executes* the named file or object.

Comment: What if you have a bunch of objects saved in RData format?