# R: Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated

Tags: r, list, save, load

Some times ago I saved some list variables as files using save function

```
> str(ttr.varSD)
List of 4
 $ classifierLimits: Named num [1:5] 2 13 5 24 16
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "sdClose-VS" "sdDiff-VS"...
 $ trainClassLabels: num [1:497] 4 2 3 4 2 3 2 4 1 4 ...
 $ testClassLabels : num [1:497] 4 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
>
> save(ttr.varSD, file='ttr.varSD.RDS')
```

Now I want to retrieve them using `load(file='ttr.varSD.RDS')` function but it returns this error.

```
>load(file='ttr.varSD.RDS')

  Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
  In addition: Warning message:
  file ‘ttr.varSD.RDS’ has magic number 'X'
   Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437349/bad-restore-file-magic-number-error-in-r) suggests using `read.table` function but my data is not a table. But I tested it any way and it returned this which is clearly not my complete data:

```
> read.table('ttr.varSD.RDS')
          V1
1          X
2 sdClose-VS
3 sdClose-US
Warning messages:
1: In read.table("objects/ttr.varSD.RDS") :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table("objects/ttr.varSD.RDS") :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table("objects/ttr.varSD.RDS") :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table("objects/ttr.varSD.RDS") :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'ttr.varSD.RDS'
```

Is there any chance to retrieve these files or all of them has been corrupted. To know my working environment , as it might matter, I am using R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) with RStudio on windows 7,synchronizing all my work with google drive and have git version control.

Comment: No luck with `readRDS`?

Comment: Thank you @Pascal you saved me a bunch of time. I Think you should make it an answer so other might have same question.

Comment: I've had this error while attempting to read an .rdata file. Using `readRDS` instead of `load` did the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use function `readRDS` to restore an object stored in a .RDS file. In your case:

```
readRDS('ttr.varSD.RDS')
```