# Update custom R package data

Tags: r, r-package

I built a custom R package a while back that has served me well. And now I have a dataset that is configured that I have used across multiple projects. I put the script `sample_pop.R` into `/R` in my package and ran it successfully to save `RData` df to the `/data` directory.

When I went to re-build I got the following error:

```
Warning: file 'sample_pop.RData' has magic number 'X' Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
Error in load(zfile, envir = envir) : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
```

Is this the right way to add data to an R package such that I can access my own data like I access `diamonds` via `ggplot` library?

```
library(ggplot2)
diamonds %>% head()
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463583/the-cause-of-bad-magic-number-error-when-loading-a-workspace-and-how-to-avoid  and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437349/bad-restore-file-magic-number-error-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1 Do you have a link or snippet of code used to make the data set?

Comment: Stupidly forgot I switched from saveRds and should have been using save()

Comment: Is it safe to mark it as a duplicate then so future users can find it?

Comment: I was going to delete question?

Comment: I think you can leave it since it talks about package data(unique scenario, useful).